# Design time exception not caught in .Net Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, exception, design-time

I have a form that is used at design-time to configure various properties.
I've tried two ways to do a form-level catch all exception:

(1) I add a handler to Application.ThreadException in the constructor.
(2) I wrap the Show method, of the form, in a Try/Catch block

Both of these work at run-time when I test by adding a property grid to a form and set my component as the SelectedObject.

However, at design-time the form simply closes with no message whatsoever; neither my message nor any message explaining that there is an unhandled exception.

Any ideas?

ETA: This is not about debugging at design-time. It's about how to present the user with a friendly message when my type editor encounters an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an `Application` object at design-time technically, and it doesn't call the `Show()` method the same way you do. The best way to catch the exception is to surround the offending  method or property that the designer is having a problem loading with a try/catch and throw the exception.

Just for a test, go ahead and add a dummy property to your form, called `IamGoingToThrowAnException`, and in the getter for the property do a `throw new System.Exception("Caught me in design mode")`, as follows:

```
public string IamGoingToThrowAnException 
{
    get
    {
        throw new System.Exception("Caught me in design mode.");
    }
}
```

The same thing works for any methods, or properties that are initialized through the `InitializeComponents` method, or constructor of your form.